# Use Nifi replaceText to swap first or last occurance of char/string with another string?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

Trying to add tag to incoming nifi json flowfile.

Input:

```
[{"HIT":"DUMMY_3","BatchId":"jkajks981n-1280189nd-129dnbj-2349nbfk","Id":"81274376231"}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"nifi_received_ts_est":"2018-10-04 09:31:50.108","HIT":"DUMMY_3","BatchId":"jkajks981n-1280189nd-129dnbj-2349nbfk","Id":"81274376231"}]
```

Tried different methods and am close to this now:

```
Search Value: ^([^\[]*)
Replacement Value: [{"nifi_received_ts_est":"${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS")}"\,$2
Replacement Strategy: Regex Replace
Evaluation Mode: Entire Text
```

But result is not what is expected. getting below:

```
[{"nifi_received_ts_est":"2018-10-04 09:31:50.108",$2[{"HIT":"DUMMY_3","BatchId":"jkajks981n-1280189nd-129dnbj-2349nbfk","Id":"81274376231"}]
```

Never was good in regexp... :( can someone help with the correct phrase to search and replace? Also if someone can explain the regexp and how grouping is done it would help as well. Perhaps a good cheatsheet reference. What is a good site to test and parse nifi specific regexp expressions?

SOLUTION: 
If it helps anyone found the pattern: Search Value: ^(.*?)[{ (will do lazy search until finds first '[{' and groups stuff before it to $1) so replacement will be: $1{"nifi_received_ts_est":"${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS")}",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the `search value` to `^(\[\{)(.*)`

in this case the first group `(\[\{)` will match first two symbols

and the second group `(.*)` the rest of the string

Comment: thanks... its working, but I need to make sure the search is lazy, and it only replaces the first occurrence. and conversely for '}]' the last occurance. How can I enforce that?

Comment: when `Evaluation Mode: Entire Text` then the `^` at the beginning of the `Search Value` means beginning of the whole text - so once.

Comment: I am considering the fact that incoming message may have empty spaces between ^ and '[{'. But i guess this approach should be fine. May I know if there is any way to replace operation on case basis? 

for e.g:
if found first occurrence of '[{' replace with 'ABC' and if found first occurrence of '{' replace with 'XYZ'. 

Is it possible to do this with single replaceText processor?

Comment: If it helps anyone, found the pattern:
Search Value: ^(.*?)\[{
(will do lazy search until finds first '[{' and groups stuff before it to $1)

so replacement will be: 
$1{"nifi_received_ts_est":"${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS")}",

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to use a regex here. The correct approach would be to decode the JSON string into a Perl data structure, add your new data to the structure and then encode it back to JSON.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Time::Piece;

my $json_parser = JSON->new;

my $json = '[{"HIT":"DUMMY_3","BatchId":"jkajks981n-1280189nd-129dnbj-2349nbfk","Id":"81274376231"}]';

my $data = $json_parser->decode($json);

$data->[0]->{nifi_received_ts_est} =
  localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

$json = $json_parser->encode($data);

say $json;
```

Comment: Need to add the nifi_timestamp so trying to use existing replaceText processor.

Comment: @StrangerThinks: Then why is this question tagged with "Perl"?

Comment: apologies. It seems nifi uses Java regular expressions instead of perl. I mistakenly tagged it to perl